# How I can do it: typed Extension for Arraylist

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist, collections, get

I try it:

```
fun <T : E> ArrayList<E>.getTypeOrNull(index:Int) : T? {
  val item = this.getOrNull(index)
  return if(item is T) item else null
}
```

How I can do it? I am newb on kotlin java

Answer (score 2):

do you really need an extension for it? To call the extension you have to pass the concrete type of `T` right? Otherwise, he function doesn't know which type to check.

How about simply:

```
yourResult = yourList[5] as? ConcreteT
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check requirements because the function seems strange:

But if you really need it:

```
inline fun <TE : Any, reified T: TE> ArrayList<TE>.getTypeOrNull(index:Int) : T? =
    getOrNull(index) as? T
```

and now you can use it:

```
fun test() {
    val list = ArrayList<CharSequence>()
    val str: String? = list.getTypeOrNull(5)
}
```

Comment: Thx, I think it must to help me